# Classification of real Clifford algebras

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, mp.mathematical-physics, clifford-algebras, dirac-operator

$\DeclareMathOperator\Cl{Cl}$Let $V$ be a real vector space of dimension $p+q$. Let $Q$ be a non-degenerate quadratic form on $V$ of signature $(p,q)$ where $p$ is the number of positive eigenvalues, and $q$ is the number of negative ones.

The Clifford algebra $\Cl(p,q)$ is the quotient of the tensor algebra $\oplus_{k=0}^\infty V^{\otimes k}$ modulo the two sided ideal generated by elements $v^2-Q(v)$ for any $v\in V$.

**I am looking for a classification up to an isomorphism of $\Cl(p,q)$. The cases $p=1,q=3$ and $p=3,q=1$ are of special interest. A reference would be helpful.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The classification is described in quite some detail [in the Wiki on the topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_Clifford_algebras#Classification).

In particular, the case $(p,q)=(1,3)$ is isomorphic to $M_2(\mathbb H)$ and the case $(p,q)=(3,1)$ is $M_4(\mathbb R)$.

Based on what you've said, it looks like this is what you're looking for.

It should not be hard to turn up useful matter with details online.

E.g. https://empg.maths.ed.ac.uk/Activities/Spin/Lecture2.pdf

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Clifford+algebra

I'm afraid I don't have a specific text to recommend, but I would be interested in seeing one...